# Creating form_for for atributes User image and description

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails application with devise, and I added to users a profile image, and a description. What I want to do is to create a page (DIFFERENT of the default registration/edit) where the users, after logged in, can set only this two atributes(image and description).

```
        <%= form_for(:user, html: { method: :put, :multipart => true })) do |f| %>
         <div class="form-group">
           <%= f.label :Profile_Image %>
           <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group"> 
          <%= f.label :Descrição %>
            <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control", rows: "10" %>
         </div>
        <% end %>
```

I have already tried two different controllers and none of them worked:

```
def edit
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

My config -> routes are:

```
get "edit" => "pages#edit"
post "edit" => "pages#edit"
```

But when i click submit it does nothing! I am new at rails and I am trying to figure this out for hours... How can I create a page to update only the image and the description? Thanks

Comment: can you show us your controller and what version of rails are you running? Also stacktrace when you click submit form?

Comment: My rails version is 4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an update method in your controller.  Your edit method allows the form to render, but you need something like this:

```
def update
   current_user.update(user_params)
end
```

Then you would have another method in your controller called user_params, which would look something like this.  I was taught to put it under a private heading.

```
private
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:profile_image, :description)
   end
```

I believe there is a shortcut way of including your params with your update method, but this will do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use registration controller devise and you should customize it.
2. You should have one method with the same name in one controller, you have two edit method. Change one edit method to update method ( reference : [Allow users to edit their account](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) )

   **pages_controller.rb**

   ```
   class PagesController < Devise::RegistrationsController

   def edit
    @user = current_user
   end

   def update
    @user = current_user

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))
    else
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update))
    end

    if successfully_updated
     set_flash_message :notice, :updated
     # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
     sign_in @user, :bypass => true
     redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
     render "edit"
    end
   end

   private
   def needs_password?(user, params)
     user.email != params[:user][:email] || params[:user][:password].present?
   end
   end
   ```

   **application_controller.rb**

   ```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
       u.permit(:description, :image, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
     end
   end
   end
   ```
3. You have wrong http verb (post), you need `PUT/PATCH` not `POST`

   ```
   devise_scope :user do
    get "edit" => "pages#edit"
    put "update" => "pages#update"
   end
   ```
4. On your view looks like (example and not tested)

   ```
   <%= form_for(@user, :url => update_pages_path, :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
     <%= devise_error_messages! %>
     <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :image, "Profile Image" %>
       <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group"> 
       <%= f.label description, "Descrição" %>
       <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control", rows: "10" %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
   <%= f.submit "Save Image" %>
   ```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried to follow the devise tutorial and its not working out too, all I need is exactly it, I want to let users update without password, but I follow all this steps and nothing... The ''current psasword can't be blank continues...'' Can you please explain pass by pass how to follow the tutorial you linked?

Comment: updated answer, **Can you please explain pass by pass how to follow the tutorial you linked?** I think the tutorial have explained what do you want