# creating form_for @user on different page than devise/registrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, form-for

I'm trying to build a site in which a user can signup by inputing just their email address and password (Rails app/ Devise authentication) and once they complete that they can provide additional details, such as an "about me" field, and date of birth, etc.

I was following this post on Stack overflow which seems to be asking the same exact thing: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443169/creating-form-for-for-atributes-user-image-and-description)

I followed the steps provided in that answer but my field are not saving to the database.

Here is the relevant code in my profiles#show page:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: updateprofile_path, html: { method: :put, :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :about, class: "form-control", rows: "10", placeholder: "Tell us about yourself." %>
  <div><%= f.submit "Update", :class => "btn btn-default btn-xs" %></div>
<% end %>
```

The path **updateprofile** derives from my custom route in my routes file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new', as: :register
    get 'signin', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: :signin
    get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
    get 'edit', to: 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :edit
    put "update" => 'devise/registrations#update', as: :updateprofile
  end
```

Here is my registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute
      # update_without_password doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to profiles_show_path(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

private

  # check if we need password to update user data
  # ie if password or email was changed
  # extend this as needed
  def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
    params[:user][:password].present? ||
    params[:user][:password_confirmation].present?
  end

  def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :date_of_birth, :about, :avatar, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

end
```

The update method in the registrations controller I got from the devise documentation on this subject: [Link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

Since this hasn't worked I'm doubting if it is what I needed to do. The result of all of this is that I will click on Submit after entering in the about field, and it will route it to the /update path, which is a blank template (I just created it to override the missing template error). I ran User.all in my rails console and confirmed that the about field is still null.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I have spent many many hours trying to figure this out and would love any help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not mess with any devise controllers. What you would like to do can be achieved like so:

1) Simply add the fields you would like to the User model (about_me, date_of_birth).....Then modify your Application Controller like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :about_me, :date_of_birth
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :about_me, :date_of_birth
   end
end
```

Once you have done this, you can add the fields to the registration page if you would like. Else, you can just add the fields in the form for devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

Once you provide people with a link to their edit registration path, they will be able to add the additional information and update their profile.

Comment: Hi fresh, thanks for your answer. This solved the underlying problem of getting the form to submit and save to the database. One minor syntax problem to correct in the configure_permitted_parameters method: when declaring multiple fields you are supposed to use a loop and pass in a |u| parameter. Such as:devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit(:date_of_birth, :about)

Answer (score 0):

By default devise views uses methods such as resource and resource_name. If creating a new Registrations controller as recommended above for use with the default views generated by Devise, you may find it helpful to re-define these methods in a RegistrationsHelper:

```
module RegistrationsHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

I have read it from Devise wiki [Custom Registration Controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password#using-a-custom-registrations-controller-with-devise-views)

Hope it will help you